# Using the epsilon delta criterion to show discontinuity in a point

Tags: epsilon-delta

I am working on the following exercise:
Use the $\epsilon-\delta$-criterion to show that the following function is discontinuous in $0\\$

$sgn(x) = \begin{cases}
          -1&,\text{ for }x<0\\
           0&,\text{ for }x=0 \\
           1&,\text{ for }x>0
          \end{cases} $

Intuitively this makes sense but I am struggling with arguing for this. More specifically, do I have to argue for each of the cases? Also, how would you advise choosing delta in the beginning? What I have so far is:

$\epsilon-\delta$ criterion: Let $f : D \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $x_{0} \in D.$ Then, $f$ is continuous at $x_{0}$ if and only if $\forall \epsilon > 0 \quad \exists \delta > 0 \quad \forall x \in D : |x - x_{0} | < \delta  \implies |f(x) - f(x_{0}| < \epsilon$

Let $\epsilon > 0$ Set $\delta = 1 \\$

Case 1: $|x - 0| < 1 \implies |-1 - 0 | < \epsilon \\|x| < 1 \implies 1 < \epsilon$

Not true if we set $\epsilon = 2\delta = 2$

Case 2: $|x - 0| < 1 \implies |1 - 0 | < \epsilon \\|x| < 1 \implies 1 < \epsilon$

Not true with the same argument

Edit: Sorry, the original post had two typos. (In the definitions)

Answer (score 3):

Take $\varepsilon=1$. Then, for any $\delta>0$, you have$$\left|\frac\delta2-0\right|<\delta\quad\text{and}\quad\left|\operatorname{sgn}\left(\frac\delta2\right)-\operatorname{sgn}(0)\right|=1\geqslant\varepsilon.$$So, this proves that$$(\exists\varepsilon>0)(\forall\delta>0)(\exists x\in\Bbb R):|x-0|<\delta\text{ and }\bigl|\operatorname{sgn}(x)-\operatorname{sgn}(0)\bigr|\geqslant\varepsilon,$$which is the same thing as asserting that $\operatorname{sgn}$ is discontinuous at $0$.